# Share data between ng-init and factory

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller, ng-init

In my application I have to retrieve the data set by the factory recursively from the `init` method as given below .Ii tried using a new `Factory` object but that threw error that `Fact is undefined` in the `init` method.

```
angular.module('name-App').factory('Fact', function(){
  return { Field: '' };
});


angular.module('name-App').factory('httpcall', function($http,$rootScope,$cookies,Fact) {

   return {

        getVal: function(stock) 
        {

             //return the promise directly.
             return  $http({
                                   url:'https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=w&q='+stock, 
                                   method: "GET",
                                // params: {d1:st1,d2:st2}
                                  // params:{d:stock}
                           }).success(function(dx,status)
                            {   var metad =JSON.stringify(dx);
                                console.log("data in success metad.substring(3,metad.length-) ="+dx.substring(3,dx.length-1));
                                $rootScope.share=JSON.parse(dx.substring(3,dx.length-1));
                                // $rootScope.defStorage.push($rootScope.share);
                          Fact= $rootScope.share;//------->>>>>I NEED TO ACCESS THIS VALUE IN INIT METHOD
                                console.log(status+"-------JSON.stringify($scope.defStorage) ="+JSON.stringify($rootScope.defStorage));
                              //return result.dx;   
                            })
                             .catch(function(fallback) 
                             {
                              alert("failed in http call with ="+fallback + '!!');
                             });
    }
  }
});



$scope.init = function () {


        var ex=$cookies.get("arr") ;
        $scope.arry= JSON.parse(ex);


        //create a call to google api for all stocks in the $scope.arry
    $scope.arry.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log("entry is "+entry);
    httpcall.getVal(entry);
    $scope.arry.push(Fact); // Fact not defined
    console.log("Fact"+Fact);
});
```

Is there any other way by which I can access `$rootScope.share` in the `init` method ?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: is the '$scope.init' function in some other controller? and are you injecting the 'Fact' factory into that controller?

Comment: @o4ohel no its in the same controller nameApp

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried creating a factory with a constructor function to init it?

check out this tutorial:

[Create Factory with parameters](https://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/how-to-create-a-factory-in-angularjs-that-takes-parameters/)

Hope it helps :)